# How to download files from a Linux server from the command line?

Tags: linux, download

I'd like to start using my localhost to develop from. I am trying to work out the best way to sync my local folder with the files directory on the remote web server. In some cases there will be 10,000+ files.

This is not for component files such as php, css, javascript etc. This is for content and media files which I do not wish to use git/svn for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always rsync

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rsync.htm

It is built for exactly this kind of task, and optimized for syncing when there are small deltas to large file sets.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using rsync. It's built specifically for remote synchronization tasks. Take a look at the compression and differential modes.

Answer (score 0):

if rsync is out of the question you can try [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), it has some nifty fetuers.